# MySQL Select Query 17000 rows slow

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb

The problem is that when I display about 17000 records on the page it takes a long time and when I open this page a couple of times in new tabs they load only when the first page is loaded.

Normally this is stupid because web applications should work multithreaded.

I don't understand why this is so.

I use indexes to load things faster and it doesn't bring anything, I think. If I use PHPMyAdmin to load the data with a `SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 30000` load, it takes 10 minutes and then comes a server error. I don't know why that is so.

How can I increase the speed to insert, read and write data and so on?

This page selects 2002 comments (data sets) and is already slow
https://www.prodigy-official.de/punity/questions/show?question=11

This page selects 17000 rows and does not loads...
https://www.prodigy-official.de/punity/questions/show?question=10

WHY

I use InnoDB as Engine.

I use a Virtual Machine.

Infos:

http://prntscr.com/pm8e9j

Comment: ehm. if many users comment on a question, YES?!

Comment: @Salman A Would you just help me instead of asking me why I'm doing this?

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch04.html check this out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484874/mysql-big-tables-slow-queries

Comment: _Normally this is stupid because web applications should work multithreaded_ are you using PHP sessions? That _might_ explain it.

Comment: I don't have a big table. The table has rows under 30000. And 30000 for a mysql is a joke. 1 Million is big but 30000 not

Comment: Yeah i use because Im working on a question platform like stackoverflow and there i need php sessions for user login and so on, how can I increase of php, mysql and so on?

Comment: you should provide your sql code  ..and your table schema   you should also check if is the query slow  on the data retrival (download to the page ) in the webbrowser

Comment: Sessions... hmmm. The page seems to take 19 seconds to generate; if you have called session_start then opening another page from this website in a new tab will be stalled for those 19 seconds. As for 19 seconds... it could be common mistakes... using `SELECT * FROM` instead of `SELECT id, comment, time`... missing indexes etc. Finally, 17000 comments on a single page is nonsense. Use some kind of paging mechanism, lazy-load etc.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qxUpe9kg this is my php page i use to show the question.

Comment: I already select all queries without the *. Which index should i create for which columns?

Comment: `WHERE ... ORDER BY ...`   `WHERE ... AND ... `... requires compound/composite  (multicolumn) indexes.. -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Raymond. Ok how can i create this? My current table design is: http://prntscr.com/pm8wsd

Comment: *"Ok how can i create this?"* [CREATE INDEX Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) it should all be all explained in there..

Comment: I created this now: http://prntscr.com/pm8zjm one index with 3 columns. And the page is still slow. wow

Comment: If the page loads: http://prntscr.com/pm90pu

Comment: indexing is a art form you can't simply create indexes to hope it is faster ... You need to log  with slow_log .. Run EXPLAIN on those query and analyze why are slow... Sometimes indexing is not enough and a complete SQL code write is required aswell..

Comment: EXPLAIN : http://prntscr.com/pm9ccy

Comment: I see two _different_ `SELECTs` on that page.  Please copy the _relevant_ on _into your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Glancing through the code, it seems like you display a question, plus all its comments?

```
$question_id = $_GET['question'];
SELECT  id,username_id,question_id,comment,comment_date
    FROM  `user.comments`
    WHERE  `question_id` = $question_id
      AND  is_reply_from_comment_id = '0'
    ORDER BY  id 
foreach result
{
    SELECT  id,username_id,comment,comment_date
        FROM  `user.comments`
        WHERE  is_reply_from_comment_id = $comment_id
        ORDER BY  id 
}
```

For the sanity of your users, you *must* put a limit on the number of comments displayed all at once.

Replacing `INDEX(is_reply_from_comment_id)` with `INDEX(is_reply_from_comment_id, question_id)` will help the first `SELECT` without hurting the second.

Do you understand that the schema limits the table to only 32K rows?  (It sounds like you will soon hit that limit.)