# 'select * from ALargeTable' executes very slow in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'prices':

```
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
    `dt` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
    `buy` double NOT NULL,
    `sell` double NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`dt`),
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_dt_buy_sell` (`dt`,`buy`,`sell`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

with about 22 millions of rows.

a simple query

```
select * from prices;
```

takes about 1 minute to execute.

What does MySQL do for 1 minute? What data structures does it build? Is there a way to optimize this?

For example a query

```
select * from prices limit 10;
```

executes immediately in 0.00 seconds.

I played a bit with transaction isolation level, with commands like

```
set SESSION transaction isolation level Read committed;
SELECT @@transaction_ISOLATION;
```

but with no success.

MySQL version is 5.7.30

Comment: Note that money is almost never DOUBLE; it's why DECIMAL was invented

Comment: That said, short of buying a faster machine, I doubt that there's much you can do here.

Comment: which version of mysql are you running? what are the specs of your db instance? did you try to have a look at the explain (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484874/mysql-big-tables-slow-queries) and to the slow queries logs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html ?

Comment: It just takes time to send 22 million rows over the database connection.

Comment: I don't think you can optimize this. 22 million rows fetched and rendered takes a while. What is the use case for selecting 22 million rows? doing a backup?

Comment: The time isn't being taken performing the query itself. It's just send the results to the client.

Comment: @mankowitz not a backup, but some statistical analysis of all the prices

Comment: @mabe02 MySQL version is 5.7.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening ? The MYSQL server is reading data from your disk, and loading it into memory (if it is not already in memory) and sending the data to the MYSQL client, who is storing it in memory, before prompting it to the user (you).

What data structures does it build? I do not know, but I am not sure if it really matters.

Is there a way to optimize this? Yes, read less data, or check your configuration and your hardware, (and if you have concurrency issues you may need to change the engine).

- read less data : as you have seen, with a `limit 10` the query runs fast, maybe you do not need 22 millions returned for every query, and you can add a `WHERE` clause.
- check your hardware : the data is on the disk, make sure you have a fast disk (like a SSD), also make sure you have enough memory on the server
- check your configuration : there are better answers on the internet that will explain how to tune your configuration, in a short (and inaccurate way) you want all your data to be able to be stored in memory, if you are only reading data, I would advise looking at this answer : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/136409/119372 : increase your `key_buffer_size` to match the size of your index if it is not already done, and try the other suggestions one by one to see if any or all have an effect on your performances
- about concurrency : my guess was that this table was read only, if you are inserting / updating the data while querying it, MyIsam does a table lock, so you could try InnoDB to avoid this table lock

On a side note, as @Barmar pointed you are testing the server and the client at the same time, and you do not say if both are running on the same server. Most likely you are, so the memory can be consumed by your MYSQL server and your MYSQL client.